# How to trim characters in Python?

Tags: python, string, subscript

Very new to Python and have very simple question. I would like to trim the last 3 characters from string. What is the efficient way of doing this?

Example  `I am going` becomes `I am go`

Answer (score 16):

You can use `new_str = old_str[:-3]`, that means all from the beginning to three characters before the end.

Comment: More generally, negative indexes on strings and lists refer to the end of the sequence, e.g., string[-1] is the last character.

Answer (score 7):

Slicing sounds like the most appropriate use case you're after if it's mere character count; however if you know the actual string you want to trim from the string you can do an [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip)

```
x = 'I am going'
>>> x.rstrip('ing')
'I am go'
>>> x.rstrip('noMatch')
'I am going'
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry to have mislead but these examples are misleading, the argument to `rstrip` is not being processed as an ordered string but as an unordered set of characters.

all of these are equivalent

```
>>> x.rstrip('ing')
'I am go'
>>> x.rstrip('gni')
'I am go'
>>> x.rstrip('ngi')
'I am go'
>>> x.rstrip('nig')
'I am go'
>>> x.rstrip('gin')
'I am go'
```

**Update 2**

If suffix and prefix stripping is being sought after there's now dedicated built in support for those operations.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/#remove-multiple-copies-of-a-prefix

Answer (score 3):

Use [string slicing](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html#slicingstrings).

```
>>> x = 'I am going'
>>> x[:-3]
'I am go'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [:-3] right after the name of the string. That would give you a string with all the characters from the start, up to the 3rd from last character. Alternatively, if you want the first 3 characters dropped, you could use [3:]. Likewise, [3:-3] would give you a string with the first 3, and the last 3 characters removed.